# validation not working on edittext

Tags: android

i have done some validation on single value and it is working but in this code ,validation is not working 
please give some answer. it does not give any error 
it simply goes to the next activity.and not validating anything.

```
package com.example.snooder;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;

public class players extends Activity {





LinearLayout player_layout;
Bundle b;
EditText[] ed1;

List<EditText> allEds = new ArrayList<EditText>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.players);

    b = getIntent().getExtras();
    String resStr = b.getString("name");

    player_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.player_layout);

     ed1 = new EditText[Integer.parseInt(resStr)+1];
    Button add_player = new Button(players.this);
    add_player.setText("Add Players");


    for(int i=1;i<=Integer.parseInt(resStr);i++)
    {
        ed1[i] = new EditText(players.this);
        allEds.add(ed1[i]);
        player_layout.addView(ed1[i]);
        ed1[i].setId(i);
        ed1[i].setHint("enter player" +i+ "name");
        ed1[i].setHeight(50);
        ed1[i].setWidth(300);




    }

    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    player_layout.addView(add_player, lp);

    add_player.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (ed1== null )
            {


                for(int i=0; i < allEds.size()+1; i++)
                {
                    if(null== ed1 || ed1[i].length() == 0)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "please enter player name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
            else
            {

                Intent intent = new Intent(players.this,player_name.class);
                String[] strings = new String[allEds.size()];

                for(int i=0; i < allEds.size(); i++)
                {
                    strings[i] = allEds.get(i).getText().toString();
                    intent.putExtra("playerName",strings);
                }
                startActivity(intent);

            }


        }
    });












}

}
```

Comment: If `(ed1 != null)` it goes to `startActivity`. It's always `!= null` when you click the button...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are gonna be interested in this GitHub project:

https://github.com/vekexasia/android-form-edittext